# The meaning of 'quirk aside'

Tags: meaning-in-context, vocabulary

I read a sentence 'Some personality **quirks aside**,' in the following context

> When I was a kid, our neighbors had two twin cats. They looked seem- ingly identical—the same charcoal fur and the same piercing green eyes.
>    **Some personality **quirks aside****, you couldn’t tell them apart just from looking at them.But of course, they were two different cats, two separate beings, even though they looked exactly the same.

Psersonality is a noun,so 'quirk' should be a verb.

In [Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/personality), it reads

> 1.Noun
>   A peculiar aspect of a person's character or behaviour.
>   2.Verb
>   (with reference to a person's mouth or eyebrow) move or twist suddenly, especially to express surprise or amusement.

From the definition, a verb doesn't make sense. If a noun, I'm unable to parse its grammar and catch its meaning.

Comment: You can rephrase the sentence as "Aside from some personality quirks,".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Psersonality is a noun,so 'quirk' should be a verb.

Not that simple, unfortunately.  Commas do not necessarily end clauses in sentences.

> Some personality quirks aside, you couldn’t tell them apart just from looking at them.

The subject of this sentence is *you* and the verb is *could not tell*.

I think what is happening is that *some personality quirks aside* is an adverbial phrase - things that answer the question or provide more information toward the question *how?* are generally adverbs and modify/qualify the verb in the sentence.